# How to see "Process c=Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "java C:\\file");" output?

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to exec class file(java class file) using process statement. But I am unable to figure out how to see output on screen.

Comment: Would you mind reading the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream())?

Comment: I did this  InputStream inputStream = c.getInputStream();
 InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
InputStream errorStream = c.getErrorStream();
 InputStreamReader esr = new InputStreamReader(errorStream);BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(c.getInputStream());
 byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
 while (in.read(bytes) != -1) {} But nothing happens.

Comment: Of course, nothing happens. You should output the read content: `while (...) {System.out.println (new String(bytes));}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to run like Runtime.getRuntime().exec( ”java C:/file > c:/output.txt“); this will save the output into a file "output.txt" at c:\.

Comment: I did this thing also .. But the text file always has error "Class file not found". Although class file exist in same folder as the text and java files.